# Need to convert the set character to (*) symbol in string value

Tags: php

I want to display the set of characters as * symbol in string using php

For example:

Input: DKK8797365A367653657

Result : ****************3657

can anyone help me ?

Comment: how many leading characters do you want to convert to * ? use substr() to remove N characters then add as many * in front as you need

Comment: There is no limit. But main thing is that, Should convert all characters to (*) symbol except last 4 digits

Answer (score 3):

If the length of the strings is constant, you want to extract the 4 chars tail of the string. Use `substr()` for that.

```
$input = 'DKK8797365A367653657';
$tail = substr($input, -4);

// Echo the tail preceded by a constant amount of *
echo '***************' . $tail;
```

If the amount of characters that should be replaced by `*` is *not* constant, you can take advantage of the function `str_repeat()`:

```
$input = 'DKK8797365A367653657';
// The head of the string, until the last 4 chars
$head = substr($input, 0, -4);
// The last 4 chars
$tail = substr($input, -4);

// Echo as much * as characters are in head
echo str_repeat('*', strlen($head)) . $tail;
```

Answer (score 0):

@hek2mgl 's code works fine! But, if you want, you can also try wit this code:

```
<?php
$input= "DKK8797365A367653657";
$show = 4;

echo str_repeat("*", (strlen($input)-$show)).substr($input,-4);
?>
```

You only need to change the value of $show by the number of characters you want to show.
This code is in a note of php.net but modified to show only the last 4 characters.

The original code can be found in a note, here: http://php.net/str-repeat